# No way to insert a page break in a table. (Razor page)

Tags: html, razor-pages

I have this code in a razor Page:

```
<table class="table table-sm table-bordered w-95 mx-auto h6">
<thead>
    ...
</thead>
<tbody>
    @while (!eof)
    {
        var item = Model.LstRecords[nReg];

        <tr>...</tr>

        eof = (nRec == lastRec);
        nRec += 1;

        if (nLin == nMaxLins && !eof)
        {
            nPag += 1;
            nLin = 1;

            <tr><td style="break-after:always"></td></tr>
        }
        else {
            nLin += 1;
        }
    }
</tbody>
<tr>...</tr> <!-- For totals -->
</table>
```

I try to insert a page break when condition is met and it is impossible. I have already tried with `<br/>` but it does not work, the line is inserted like one more row. Also I try with style="page-brake-after: always", also with before, also brake-after: page etc.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I presume you would have to split the table.  When you want a page break, close the table, do the pagebreak,  then start a new table.

Comment: Thanks. It works fine. I post the new logic.

Answer (score 0):

New code:

```js
@while (!eof)
{
    <table class="table table-sm table-bordered w-95 mx-auto h6">
        <thead>
            ...
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @while (!eof && nLin <= nMaxLins)
            {
                var item = Model.LstRecords[nReg];
        
                <tr>...</tr>
        
                eof = (nRec == lastRec);
                nRec += 1;
                nLin = 1;
        
                @if (eof)
                {
                    <tr>...</tr> <!-- Totals -->
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

    nPag += 1; nLin = 1; nMaxLins = 24;

    if (!eof) {
        <p class="pagebreak"></p>
    }
}
```

Tip: to avoid extra blank page at the end of the report set html and body height to 99%

Thank you very much for your comment Petern.